# Detectar colisiones entre fechas DOCTRINE

Tags: php, mysql, sql, doctrine2

Tengo una tabla `TAREAS` formado de la siguiente forma:

```
+--------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id     | informe_id | inicio              | fin                 |
+--------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 569811 |     266667 | 2017-07-17 09:10:00 | 2017-07-17 14:50:00 |
| 569810 |     266667 | 2017-07-17 00:00:00 | 2017-07-17 01:10:00 |
| 569809 |     266664 | 2017-07-12 00:00:00 | 2017-07-13 09:50:00 |
| 569808 |     266663 | 2017-07-12 00:00:00 | 2017-07-13 05:50:00 |
| 569807 |     266662 | 2017-07-11 19:00:00 | 2017-07-11 20:00:00 |
| 569806 |     266661 | 2017-07-10 16:00:00 | 2017-07-10 17:30:00 |
|    ... |        ... |                 ... |                 ... |   
+--------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Existen más datos, sólo he puesto una parte.

Resulta que, entre los datos, existen casos en los que una tarea de un informe coincide o, más bien dicho, "colisiona" entre otras tareas de otro informes. Las tareas se solapan entre ellas. Me han pedido que indique que informes tienen tareas que colisionan **con otros informes**.

*Para hacerlo, he llegado a esta consulta:*

```
SELECT a.id, a.informe_id as informe_a, a.inicio as inicio_a, a.fin as fin_a, b.id, b.informe_id as informe_c, b.inicio as inicio_b, b.fin as fin_b 
FROM tareas a, tareas b 
WHERE a.informe_id <> b.informe_id
AND a.id <> b.id
AND (
    ( a.inicio between b.inicio and b.fin )
OR  ( a.fin    between b.inicio and b.fin )
OR  ( b.inicio between a.inicio and a.fin )
OR  ( b.fin    between a.inicio and a.fin )  
)
```

*Que muestra como resultado:*

```
+--------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+--------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id     | informe_a | inicio_a            | fin_a               | id     | informe_c | inicio_b            | fin_b               |
+--------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+--------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  52881 |     27351 | 2015-02-26 08:30:00 | 2015-02-26 16:30:00 |  52921 |     27671 | 2015-02-26 08:30:00 | 2015-02-26 13:30:00 |
|  52921 |     27671 | 2015-02-26 08:30:00 | 2015-02-26 13:30:00 |  52881 |     27351 | 2015-02-26 08:30:00 | 2015-02-26 16:30:00 |
|  54141 |     28241 | 2015-03-02 08:45:00 | 2015-03-02 15:00:00 |  54371 |     28341 | 2015-03-02 08:30:00 | 2015-03-02 10:30:00 |
|  54371 |     28341 | 2015-03-02 08:30:00 | 2015-03-02 10:30:00 |  54141 |     28241 | 2015-03-02 08:45:00 | 2015-03-02 15:00:00 |
|    ... |       ... |                 ... |                 ... |    ... |       ... |                 ... |                 ... | 
+--------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+--------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Encuentro las colisiones que me interesan. (existen más datos, como en el caso anterior).

El problema que tengo es que no encuentro manera de "convertir" la consulta como `Doctrine`, ya que es un producto de tablas sin `JOIN`, y no veo en la documentación  como hacerlo.

*Como alternativa, he probado a hacer lo siguiente:*

```
$informe = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository("AppBundle:Informe")->findById($informe_id);

$inicio = $informe->getTareas()->first()->getInicio();
$fin    = $informe->getTareas()->last()->getFin();

$list = $this->getEntityManager()
    ->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('o')
    ->from('AppBundle:Informe', 'o')
    ->innerJoin('o.tareas', 't')
    ->where('(t.inicio BETWEEN :inicio AND :fin ) OR (t.fin BETWEEN :inicio AND :fin)')
    ->setParameter('inicio', $inicio)
    ->setParameter('fin', $fin)
    ->andWhere('o <> :informe')
    ->setParameter('informe', $informe)
    ->groupBy('o')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult()
```

Pero esto, aunque parece que resuelve el tema, devuelve todas las colisiones, incluidas aquellas que no lo son.

*Hay casos del tipo:*

```
+--------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id     | informe_id | inicio              | fin                 |
+--------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 569811 |     266667 | 2017-07-17 09:00:00 | 2017-07-17 10:00:00 |
| 569810 |     266667 | 2017-07-17 10:00:00 | 2017-07-17 20:00:00 |
| 569809 |     266664 | 2017-07-12 20:00:00 | 2017-07-13 21:00:00 |
+--------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Es decir, uno de los informes tiene dos tareas, una de 9 a 10h y otra de 20 a 21h, y el otro tiene de 10h a 20h, y no debería ser colisión.
Entiendo que este resultado tiene su sentido, ya que estoy cogiendo las fechas de inicio de la primera tarea de un informe, y de fin de la última tarea de un parte, pero no es el que busco, y tampoco se cómo solucionarlo.

¿Hay alguna forma de hacer la consulta de otra forma, o veis algún fallo en ella?

Answer (score 1):

Supongo que ya lo tienes solucionado. Igualmente dejare mi respuesta por aquí por si a alguien le sirve.

En la consulta haces un JOIN y puedes utilizar esos campos de la tabla del JOIN para crear la condición.

Supongamos que la tabla se llama **tareas** y tenemos los siguientes datos:

```
+----+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | informe_id | inicio              | fin                 |
+----+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 |     266667 | 2017-07-17 09:10:00 | 2017-07-17 14:50:00 |
|  2 |     266667 | 2017-07-17 00:00:00 | 2017-07-17 01:10:00 |
|  3 |     266664 | 2017-07-12 00:00:00 | 2017-07-13 09:50:00 |
|  4 |     266663 | 2017-07-12 00:00:00 | 2017-07-13 05:50:00 |
|  5 |     266662 | 2017-07-11 19:00:00 | 2017-07-11 20:00:00 |
|  6 |     266663 | 2017-07-10 16:00:00 | 2017-07-10 17:30:00 |
|  7 |         25 | 2017-07-12 00:00:00 | 2017-07-13 09:50:00 |
+----+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Haciendo la sigiente consulta

```
SELECT 
T1.id, T1.informe_id, T1.inicio, T1.fin, 
T2.id coli_id, T2.informe_id coli_inf, T2.inicio coli_inicio, T2.fin coli_fin 
FROM tareas T1
INNER JOIN tareas T2 ON  T1.id <> T2.id
and (
    ( T1.inicio between T2.inicio and T2.fin )
OR  ( T1.fin    between T2.inicio and T2.fin )
)
```

Obtenemos algo como esto:

```
+----+------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | informe_id | inicio              | fin                 | coli_id | coli_inf | coli_inicio         | coli_fin            |
+----+------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  4 |     266663 | 2017-07-12 00:00:00 | 2017-07-13 05:50:00 |       3 |   266664 | 2017-07-12 00:00:00 | 2017-07-13 09:50:00 |
|  7 |         25 | 2017-07-12 00:00:00 | 2017-07-13 09:50:00 |       3 |   266664 | 2017-07-12 00:00:00 | 2017-07-13 09:50:00 |
|  3 |     266664 | 2017-07-12 00:00:00 | 2017-07-13 09:50:00 |       4 |   266663 | 2017-07-12 00:00:00 | 2017-07-13 05:50:00 |
|  7 |         25 | 2017-07-12 00:00:00 | 2017-07-13 09:50:00 |       4 |   266663 | 2017-07-12 00:00:00 | 2017-07-13 05:50:00 |
|  3 |     266664 | 2017-07-12 00:00:00 | 2017-07-13 09:50:00 |       7 |       25 | 2017-07-12 00:00:00 | 2017-07-13 09:50:00 |
|  4 |     266663 | 2017-07-12 00:00:00 | 2017-07-13 05:50:00 |       7 |       25 | 2017-07-12 00:00:00 | 2017-07-13 09:50:00 |
+----+------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Si intentamos pasarlo a queryBuilder de doctrine podría quedar algo como esto:

```
<?php

$queryBuilder
->select(
'T1.id', 'T1.informe_id', 'T1.inicio', 'T1.fin',
'T2.id coli_id', 'T2.informe_id coli_inf', 'T2.inicio coli_inicio', 'T2.fin coli_fin'
)
->from('tareas', 'T1')
->innerJoin('T1', 'tareas', 'T2', 
    'T1.id <> T2.id
    and (
        ( T1.inicio between T2.inicio and T2.fin )
    OR  ( T1.fin    between T2.inicio and T2.fin )
    )'
);
```

Otra opción podría ser crear una vista, para facilitar las cosas, ya que ésta consulta será estática.